# Turning off the result printing in common lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am working with a reasonably large dataset in GNU clisp. It would be *really* nice if I could turn off the **P** of the REPL. Having thousands of results spew across my screen really isn't very useful.

I rummaged through the docs and couldn't find out how to turn it off. I assume it's one of the variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try changing the value of [`*print-length*`](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/var_stprint-l_int-lengthst.html).